# Why did installing php53-mcrypt break my composer and laravel?

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, homebrew, mcrypt

I am very new to laravel and php and I am just trying to set up my development environment.

I am interested in using octobercms and installing it has been anything but simple. I tried the console installation by typing

```
composer create-project october/october myoctober dev-master
```

which gave an error saying mcrypt wasn't installed so I thought that was my next step. After spending hours trying to figure out how to install it I came across this

```
homebrew/php/php53-mcrypt
```

and I brew installed it. Now, laravel and my composer won't work. Every time I write any sort of composer command, I get this:

```
??+?% returned
```

No one on google seems to have this problem and every time I write and laravel command in the terminal I get some sort of error like this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /Users/marika/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php on line 41

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /Users/marika/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php on line 41
```

it was all working before I brew installed mcrypt and I tried to uninstall but that just gave me more errors, so I reinstalled and now I don't know what else to do.

Comment: In a more general sense, I also advise against developing on your local machine using homebrew dev environment for anything than playing around with a new technology. I have been there and it has bit me furiously. My current strategy is developing using a docker container which is as close to the production server as possible. (In fact, our production servers run docker containers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong php version. At line 41 of the [functions.php of guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/b1e1c0d55f8083c71eda2c28c12a228d708294ea/src/functions.php#L41), it says:

```
    $promise = new Promise([$queue, 'run']);
```

which is short array syntax. You will need php5.4 to run your code, as the [doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) states:

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

As you are on MacOS, in order to get a more up to date version of PHP, install a newer version via:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php56
brew unlink php53
brew link php56
```

[Source](http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: so instead of php53 wouldn't I do install php54?

Comment: @begwebdev I'd go for 5.6, yet in the end >=5.4 should work fine.In the answer, I only unlinked the old php version. brew allows switching the version via un/linking so you can have multiple instances of php installed.